# Get Exif data using Uri

Tags: android, bitmap, uri, exif

I want to get `Exif` data for an image that I pick from Android gallery or similar apps like Google Photos. Here are the methods that I am using for getting image file from `Uri`:

```
public static String getActualPathFromUri(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Uri selectedImageUri) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = getBitmapFromUri(context, selectedImageUri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (bitmap == null) {
            return null;
        }

        File imageFileFolder = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "example");
        if (!imageFileFolder.exists()) {
            imageFileFolder.mkdir();
        }

        FileOutputStream out = null;

        File imageFileName = new File(imageFileFolder, "example-" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(imageFileName);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        } finally {
            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return imageFileName.getAbsolutePath();
    }

    private static Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Uri uri) throws IOException {

        ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
                context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
        assert parcelFileDescriptor != null;
        FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
        parcelFileDescriptor.close();
}
```

The reason I am opting for `Bitmap` from the `Uri` instead of getting system filename is because the method is fragmented for different versions of Android. Plus, in apps like Google Photos, some photos are shown directly from server and are not stored on the device, so getting filename is not possible. Even if I get the filename, I get `Security Exception` when trying to use that in my app.

The problem with this approach is, when I get the `Bitmap`, I don't get the `Exif` data. But I need the `Exif` data and attach it to the file that I save in my `cache` folder so that when I upload the image to server, it gets the image along with `Exif` so that it can do some further processing. The reason, I need to save it as a file or at least get the file, if it already exists in the system is because `Retrofit` needs a `File` object which then gets converted to `TypedFile` and sent to server using `Multipart` request.

So, how can I accurately get the `Exif` information from any kind of image Uri(local or on server) and then save the image along with it's `Exif` data so that I can send it to the server.